# Django "NameError: name 'CarImageForm' is not defined" for self-referencing forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, model, inline-formset

I'm following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6) to create an object creation formset. The goal is to allow multiple images connected to a car object via Foreign object, to be uploaded in a single form.

The images use a formset that has one image per field, with as many 'add another image' fields dynamically created.

Running the server raises this error: `"NameError: name 'CarImageForm' is not defined"` when self-referencing the class which encloses the definition.

I've looked through the code and found a few minor corrections, but none seem to solve this.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ImageField, CharField, TextInput

from .models import Car, Image, CustomUser

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, Fieldset, Div, HTML, ButtonHolder, Submit
from .custom_layout_object import Formset

class CarImageForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ()

    CarImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Car, Image, form=CarImageForm, fields=['car', 'image'], extra=1, can_delete=True
    )

class CreateCarForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ['seller']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CarCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...  
            )
        )
```

**Models.py (with irrelevant parts omitted)**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    car_model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    vin = models.CharField('VIN', max_length=17, help_text='Enter the 17 character VIN number.', blank=True, null=True)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Mileage')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    engine_displacement = models.CharField(default=2.0, max_length=3, help_text="Engine displacement in Liters (E.g. 2.0, 4.2, 6.3)")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
    help_text="Unique ID for this car")
...
    drivetrain = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices = DRIVETRAIN_OPTIONS,
        blank=True,
        default='4WD',
    )

...
    transmission = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=TRANSMISSION_OPTIONS,
        blank=True,
        default='5MT')
...
    forced_induction = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=FORCED_INDUCTION_OPTIONS,
        default='n',
        )

    # ensures that no model year  can be set in the future. 
    model_year = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(int(datetime.date.today().year) + 1)], null=True)
...

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=AVAILABILITY_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='a',
        help_text="Car availability",
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
        permissions = (("can_change_availability", "Mark car as sold"),)  
...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country_of_origin = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.manufacturer_name}'

class Image(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.car.manufacturer) + ' ' + str(self.car.car_model) + ' image'
```

The views aren't reached before the error is is thrown,if you need to see the file, just let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think CarImageFormset should be inside the CarImageForm class. That's not how the tutorial has it. Move it outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove indent (one tab) in those lines:

```
    CarImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Car, Image, form=CarImageForm, fields=['car', 'image'], extra=1, can_delete=True
    )
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help